# How do I rerender a FlatList after onPress action?

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, react-native-flatlist

I have a watchlist of bookings for movies and when I click on a button it deletes the booking from the Firestore database. This is the code I have:

```
const WatchList = () => {

  const uid = auth.currentUser.uid;
  const docRef = doc(db, 'users', uid);
  const [user, setUser] = useState({});
  const [watched, setWatched] = useState(true);
  const [text, setText] = useState('Watched movies');
  const [filteredBookings, setFilteredBookings] = useState(bookings);
  const bookingsRef = collection(db, "booking");

  const [bookings, setBookings] = useState({});
  useEffect(() => {
    getUser();
    getBookings();
  },[])

  const getUser = async () => {
    const snap = await getDoc(docRef)
    setUser({user, ...snap.data()})
  }

  const getBookings = async () => {
     const q = query(bookingsRef, where("users","array-contains",auth.currentUser.uid));
     const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(q, (querySnapshot) => {
     const a = [];
     querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {            
     a.push(doc.data());
  });
     setBookings(querySnapshot.docs);
    });
  }

 const deleteBooking = async(id) => {
    try {
      await deleteDoc(doc(db, 'booking', id));
    }
    catch(e) {
      console.log(e)
    }
    console.log('deleted:' + id)
  }

  return (
<View>
  <View>
    <Text>{text}</Text>
  </View>
  
  <FlatList
    data = {filteredBookings}
    numColumns = {1}

    renderItem  = {({item}) => (
      <View>
      <View>
        <Text>{item.data().movie}</Text>
        <Text>{item.data().day} - {item.data().showtime}</Text>
      </View>

      <View>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress = {() => {deleteBooking(item.id)}}>
          <Text>Delete</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
      </View>
    )}
  />
      </View>
  )
}

export default WatchList`
```

How do I get the FlatList to rerender after I press the button? When I refresh the whole app I see that it changes, but I'd like to have it rerendered after the onPress action. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

As far as I see from your implementation as data for FlatList you use `filteredBookings` but you set in only once as an initial state for `useState` hook. You need to update your list of `filteredBookings` every time you get books from the API like this:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  // filter returns new array object
  const resultOfFiltering = bookings.filter((booking) => place your condition here)
  setFilteredBookings(resultOfFiltering)
}, [bookings])
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! If I want to rerender the list for different things, how would I go about doing that?

What I mean, if I delete a booking, it will rerender the list without it. I got that to work. But if I want to set a booking as watched  and have it show up in another list (and the reverse, if I set it as unwatched and have it show up in the original), would I do it in a similar way?

Comment: yep you just change your data and create a new array but to keep it performant please follow these rules for flatlist https://reactnative.dev/docs/0.69/optimizing-flatlist-configuration

Comment: Could you please give me an example for what I could put for the filtering logic in your first comment so I would learn how to do it for the other ones? Just an example so I could know how to write for the other things I need, it's how I learn best. Thank you in advance!

Comment: It says bookings.filter is not a function when I try to do it this way, I understand how to do the conditioning, but I'm not sure how to fix this.

Comment: what is bookings I thought it is an array?

Comment: It's an array of objects pulled from Firestore

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251036/discussion-between-kirill-novikov-and-mihailo).